# Getting input from machine learning output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, data-science

I'm building a regression model to predict the efficiency of a device. Is there a way to reverse this and get the input from the model given the output? I know for some model like decision tree and random forest you can see the feature importance and for linear model you can see the weight given to each feature, but can I generate some input from this model? eg. given the best efficiency, predict the input combination.

Comment: This question is not suited for stackoverflow. You can post this on https://stats.stackoverflow.com. Anyways reversing the process then becomes single input multiple output problem, which IMO is very hard and may lead to infinite solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that there are infinitely many input options for a given output.

It's like in high school maths where you want to solve the following equation:

X + 2Y = 1

The answer could be (0,0,5), (1,0), (2,-0,5)...
You are asking for one answer when there are infinitely many answers to your question.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is mathematically impossible.

Assume you have a model that maps input channels to an output (something like X,Y -> Z).  There is exactly one output per input; this is known as one-to-one.  BUT it might not be the case that there is exactly one input per output (if there were, it would be considered onto).

Consider Z = X^2 + Y^2.

Clearly, for any X, Y we have exactly one output.  This functions is one-to-one.

However, if I was to give you Z =8, you can't give my X and Y.  It might be X=Y=2, or X=2 & Y = -2, or X = -2 & Y = 2, or X=Y=-2.